# Filter date + between dates is not possible

Tags: views

In a view I show content that contain some fields and an entity reference.

In the Fields part of the view I have a field (`Vervaldatum`) like this.

[image]

The Vervaldatum field is a date field. I would like to have a "Vervaldatum between […] and […]" filter, but when I add a filter and select the Vervaldatum field, I get this.

[image]

I was hoping to get "between […] and […]" in the operator field, but no luck. It's like the field is handles as it is a text field, but the in the previous screen it's clear it is a date field.

These are the operators that I can use.

[image]

Comment: I would just add your Vervaldatum field to the filter critera ***twice***, but set different operators for each instance of the exposed field. In other words: **Vervaldatum_1 -** Operator: Is greater than **Vervaldatum_2 -** Operator: Is less than I've never tried this method myself, but in theory it should work.

Comment: I've updated my topic and the operators you suggest are not in the list.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise that, I'm busy taking a closer look to see if I can manage to do something simliar quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following steps using a Date field and got the intended result:

**Firstly add your date field as a View filter**

[image]

**I left the configure date filter settings as default here**

[image]

**Configured the "greater than" exposed filter**

[image]

**Configured the "less than" exposed filter**

[image]

**Exposed filters appear correctly**

[image]

Those are the exact steps I followed to get the two exposed date filters. Hope you come right!

Comment: As you can see I don't have that operators ... He sees it as a text ..

Comment: Works now, my module Date Views wasn't enabled .. Thanks!